# Как очистить содержимое Canvas в Delphi?

Tags: delphi, canvas

Как очистить содержимое Canvas в Delphi?

Answer (score 1):

```
 PatBlt(Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, canvas.Width, canvas.Height,WHITENESS);
```

Comment: Не добавляйте знак цитирования: он не нужен, достаточно четырех пробелов.

Comment: У TCanvas нет свойств Width и Height, передавать нужно ClientWidth и ClientHeight компонента.